# Chain clicks when the back wheel is in highest and lowest gears

Tags: chain, gears, noise, clicking

When I have my back wheel gears in either the lowest gear or highest gear, my chain clicks as I pedal.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What gear (if you have multiple gears) is your front derailer in?

Comment: @Jack - It is really only the middle and biggest gear in the front that this happens.  The smaller front gear (lowest?) doesn't make any noise at all.

Comment: One of your derailers needs adjustment.  Could be the rear one, could be the front one.  We can't tell from here with such a limited description of the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may need to adjust your derailer limit stops ([see here](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/derailer-adjustment.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Listen to where the clicking is occurring. Look down while you pedal at the front derailleur and see if there is any rubbing. If so adjust accordingly. If there is no noticeable rubbing on the front then it is your rear derailleur that needs to be adjusted.

Be careful when doing this. I have messed it up a few times with leaves you with a bike that cant shift.

If you dont feel confident in doing this yourself a shop can do it for you rather quickly. Also a great time to get a tune up and sized if you havent been already.

Comment: But really, anybody can do this. A shop will do it right, but they'll charge you through the nose too. Just make sure you understand _how_ it works before jumping in and turning screws.